# how to deploy acronis extension on microsoft azure?

Tags: azure, backup

I'm trying to back up an azure vm to acronis, but whenever I try to deploy the acronis extension on azure I recieve the following error:

> At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
>
> VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'AcronisBackup'. Error message: "Failed to connect to Acronis Backup Cloud. Check specified credentials and firewall settings. For more information please refer to https://kb.acronis.com/content/47189"

It basically says that the provisioning state failed. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Issues related to installation of Acronis extension should be investigated with the help of Acronis support team.

Just a suggestion, you can try redeploying the VM to see if that lets you successfully install the extension. If issue persist, reach out to support and share below information with the technical professionals.

- Error details with screenshot if possible
- Detail steps followed for deployment